# Use FZF to list git files sorted by date (and set default in bash)

Tags: bash, git, fzf

I want to use fzf to list all files in git, sorted by modification date. (I use this output in vim)

This command seems to work:

```
(while read file; do echo $(git log --pretty=format:%ad -n 1 --date=raw -- $file) $file; done < <(git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD) | sort -k1,1n | awk {"print \$3"}) 2> /dev/nul
```

But how can I get this as the default FZF command?
I tried this, but the variable FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND remains empty:

```
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='
    (while read file; do echo $(git log --pretty=format:%ad -n 1 --date=raw -- $file) $file; done < <(git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD) | sort -k1,1n | awk {"print \$3"}) 2> /dev/null'
```

Maybe I need to escape something?

**Edit:** This is the command I'm now using:

```
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='(git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD)|(while read file; do echo $(git log --pretty=format:%ad -n 1 --date=raw -- "$file") $file; done | sort -r | awk {"print \$3"}) 2> /dev/null'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fzf` uses `/bin/sh` (Posix shell) to execute your command . Even if `/bin/sh` is linked to `/bin/bash` it will fail on non posix features (like process substitution in your case). You can enforce *GNU/bash* support:

```sh
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='set +o posix
    (while read file; do echo $(git log --pretty=format:%ad -n 1 --date=raw -- $file) $file; done < <(git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD) | sort -k1,1n | awk {"print \$3"}) 2> /dev/null'
```

If you don't have `bash` symlinked to  `/bin/sh`, you have to get rid of the process substitution:

```sh
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='
    (git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD)|(while read file; do echo $(git log --pretty=format:%ad -n 1 --date=raw -- $file) $file; done | sort -k1,1n | awk {"print \$3"}) 2> /dev/null'
```

Comment: The PATH variable is not empty anymore, but fzf still fails with the error [$FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND failed]

Comment: Could you verify: this output of 'file `/bin/sh` is 
`/bin/sh: symbolic link to bash`

Comment: Updated answer for `posix-shell` syntax

Comment: This is the output: '/bin/sh: symbolic link to dash'  Your new command works, but the sorting is wrong. Strange because your command is working without fzf. It seems fzf doesn't maintain the order

Comment: It works like this: fzf --no-sort --tac     Thanks!!

Comment: I reverted the sort in the command. I added the result in the question. Thanks for helping me.